# Samsung S3 Tab OpenCV camera set picture size ignored

Tags: android, opencv, camera, tablet

I am using OpenCV camera in **Samsung tab S3**. 
I am trying to set the picture size from it's supported picture size list.

By default it's picture size and preview size are same `1920x1080`. After setting picture size to `4128x2322`, when I call `mCamera.getPictureSize()` method it will return picture size `4128x2322`, but captured image size remain `1920x1080`.

I'm only changing picture size and have tried with all supported picture size list for S3: `4128x3096`, `4128x2322`, `3264x2448`, `3264x1836`, `3088x3088` etc. The result is always the same `mCamera.getPictureSize()` return size set but captured image remains `1920x1080`.

Same project in other device (Samsung J7 NXT, Huawei nova 3e and nove 2i) works as expected.

```
    int max = 1;
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Size previewSize = params.getPreviewSize();
    int previewGcd = Utility.GCD(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    List<Size> pictureSize = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

    for (Size pSize : pictureSize) {
        int pictureGcd = Utility.GCD(pSize.width, pSize.height);

        // Select largest picture size from list 
        // which aspect ratio equal to preview size

        if (Utility.isSameRatio(previewSize.width / previewGcd,
                previewSize.height / previewGcd,
                pSize.width / pictureGcd, pSize.height / pictureGcd)) {

            if (pSize.width * pSize.height > max) {
                params.setPictureSize(pSize.width, pSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
                max = pSize.height * pSize.width;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which size did you try? Did you change both preview and picture size, or only the latter?

Comment: Only picture size. Supported picture size list for S3: **4128x3096, 4128x2322, 3264x2448, 3264x1836, 3088x3088** etc. I set size **4128x2322**. After that **getPictureSize()** method return size **4128x2322**. But captured image size is **1920x1080**. On other device, it's work fine.

Comment: Now that I think about this, I wonder what role OpenCV plays here. Could there be a collision between the OpenCV camera manipulation and your setPictureSize() ?

Comment: Thanks for the addition of code. This can be very helpful to both answerers and voters/reviewers to see that you have really tried something, and what approach you have tried. Rightly or wrongly, questions featuring code are much more likely to be well-received on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You have encountered a bug in the camera library on this device. You are not the first one, and this is not the last bug in camera libraries on Android. Samsung is not not the only manufacturer that has released camera libraries with bugs.

I don't have the device here, so I cannot tell if this camera has native **camera2** API, or uses [legacy mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL). Note that support level on some devices may be different for front-facing and rare-facing cameras.

If the support level it is above **LEGACY**, consider working with this camera through its native [**camera2** API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary). This may may often be enough to resolve buggy behaviours and improve performance.

On Samsung devices, it is often necessary to use the [Samsung Camera SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera) which may be better maintained on these devices than the generic one.